# How can I use named range in Excel with OleDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb, extract

I'm trying to extract data from a specific named range in Excel with ASP .NET/C#. Here is an exemple of what I'm trying to extract.

[image: Screenshot from my Excel file]

What I want is "B", "C", "D" by using the name "RANGE_NAMED". Is it possible to do this with OleDB ?

Best regards,

Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this code

```
using(OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    c.Open();
    string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [RANGE_NAMED]";
    using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(selectString))
    {
          cmd1.Connection = c;
        var result = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while(result.Read())
        {
              Console.WriteLine(result[0].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand the query is only picking up the text data from the range. Can this be used to perform `HasFormula` on the cells in the range?

Comment: If you refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.hasformula.aspx)  then I think no because this is not used via Interop but just OleDb

Comment: I have seen that link, and just wondering whether there's such properties within `OleDb`. If in anyway we could serialized the range taken into the above `result` and deserialize it into an excel range in C# while reading via the reader. I am just thinking out loud - if you can point out any relevant info, that's great.

Comment: I can’t get this to work. It skips the while loop. I only have one value in my named range, does that effect it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It's was obvious and I don't know why it didn't work the first time...

```
SELECT * FROM RANGE_NAMED
```

And I get B, C, D.