# How to check a Cell contains formula or not in Excel through oledb reader or excel library, excel datareader or NPOI etc (Except Interop)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, winforms, oledb

How to check a Cell contains formula or not in Excel through oledb reader ?

[image]

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + strFileName + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";");
conn2.Open();
string strQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM [" + Table + "]";

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery2, conn2);

System.Data.DataTable DT2 = new System.Data.DataTable();

adapter2.Fill(DT2);
```

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in my code i just want a code to check in my excel sheet is there is any formula in any cell. Currently i am using above code to read excel and convert into data table.

Comment: as i know if you add formula  to a cell it will always return something (not null) in your case I think you can check for value is null or not null, do tell if its gives you a thought.

Comment: aspiring ,,same columns inside the table which i shown with same values, i just want to check before reading the excel sheet , Is there is any formula contain in cell or not , check my image...

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible using OLEDB

Comment: Things like these make me want to write my own Excel library!

Comment: you can Ravi , then u'll get 50 bounty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to read Xlsx files.

To do this you need to add a reference to the OpenXML library which can be done via the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) (you'll also need a reference to WindowsBase). You then need to load the spreadsheet, find the sheet you're interested in and iterate the cells.

Each [`Cell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell%28v=office.14%29.aspx) has a [`CellFormula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellformula%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property which will be non-null if there is a formula in that cell.

As an example, the following code will iterate each cell and output a line for any cell that has a formula. it will return `true` if *any* cell has a formula in it; otherwise it will return `false`:

```
public static bool OutputFormulae(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    bool hasFormula = false;

    //open the document
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
    {
        //get the workbookpart
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        //get the correct sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).First();
        if (sheet != null)
        {
            //get the corresponding worksheetpart
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;

            //iterate the child Cells
            foreach (Cell cell in worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>())
            {
                //check for a formula
                if (cell.CellFormula != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.CellFormula.Text))
                {
                    hasFormula = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cell {0} has the formula {1}", cell.CellReference, cell.CellFormula.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return hasFormula;
}
```

This can be called with the name of the file and the name of the sheet you're interested in although it would be trivial to update the code to iterate *all* sheets. An example call:

```
bool formulaExistsInSheet = OutputFormulae(@"d:\test.xlsx", "Sheet1");
Console.WriteLine("Formula exists? {0}", formulaExistsInSheet);
```

An example output from the above:

> Cell C1 has the formula A1+B1
>   Cell B3 has the formula C1*20
>   Formula exists? True

If you're only interested if there are *any* cells in the sheet that have a formula you can simplify the above by using the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:

```
public static bool HasFormula(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    bool hasFormula = false;
    //open the document
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
    {
        //get the workbookpart
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        //get the correct sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).First();
        if (sheet != null)
        {
            //get the corresponding worksheetpart
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;

            hasFormula = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Any(c =>
                c.CellFormula != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.CellFormula.Text));
        }
    }

    return hasFormula;
}
```

Comment: Good anwser, but you don't find [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML) like 100 times better?

Comment: Thanks :). Most of the Excel work I've done has been on large files so I predominantly use OpenXML due to performance (using a SAX approach rather than the above DOM approach). Given the simplicty of what the OP wants to achieve I would personally go for an MS supported wrapper but from what I've seen of ClosedXML that looks good too.

Comment: MS office required for this or not ?

Comment: No Office is not required, just OpenXML (which makes this perfectly safe to use on a server for example)

Answer (score 8):

You may explore this : [`Range.HasFormula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.hasformula.aspx) under `com-interop`.

I also noticed there's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16400302/2061309) that can be *improvised* to cater your needs.

Here's a skeleton - not the exact syntax.

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
Excel.WorkSheet WS = workBooks.WorkSheets("Sheet1");

Range rangeData = WS.Range["A1:C3"];    

foreach (Excel.Range c in rangeData.Cells)
{
    if (c.HasFormula)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(c.Value));
    }        
}
```

Not sure how you can achieve such with `OLEDB`, since your query just seems to just *grab* cell data (texts, numbers, without formulas) into the query.

If you must use `OLEDB`, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109456/2061309) can be helpful to start.
If you still need assistance, feel free to comment.

Comment: yes it can be done by this but i am not using Interop service, I want to do this only through Oledb, or Exceldatareader  ...

Answer (score 4):

I got solution but only in Interop Services!!

```
public bool IsFormulaExistInExcel(string excelpath)
     {
        bool IsFormulaExist = false;
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workBooks = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            workBook = workBooks.Open(excelpath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = workSheet.UsedRange;


            dynamic FormulaExist = rng.HasFormula;
            Type unknown = FormulaExist.GetType();

            if (unknown.Name == "DBNull")
                IsFormulaExist = true;
            else if (unknown.Name == "Boolean")
            {
                if (FormulaExist == false)
                    IsFormulaExist = false;
                else if (FormulaExist == true)
                    IsFormulaExist = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
        }
    return IsFormulaExist;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

i used Apache Poi Library... which has below relevant method

```
if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
{
// this cell contains formula......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your excel file is .xlsx, than, since .xlsx is really a zip archive, you can read xl\calcChain.xml inside it. This file contains entries like this:

```
<c r="G3" i="1" l="1"/><c r="A3" i="1" l="1"/>
```

In this example there are formulas in cells G3 and A3.
So you can do something like this:

```
    // Add references for
    // System.IO.Compression
    // System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    private static List<string> GetCellsWithFormulaInSheet(string xlsxFileName, int sheetNumber)
    {
        using (var zip = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(xlsxFileName))
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            var entry = zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FullName == "xl/calcChain.xml");
            if (entry == null)
                return list;

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(entry.Open());
            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

            return xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "c")
                .Select(x => new { Cell = x.Attribute("r").Value, Sheet = int.Parse(x.Attribute("i").Value) })
                .Where(x => x.Sheet == sheetNumber)
                .Select(x => x.Cell)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

And then use this method like this:

```
var cellsWithFormula = GetCellsWithFormulaInSheet(@"c:\Book.xlsx", 1);
bool hasFormulaInSheet = cellsWithFormula.Any();
```

Comment: i dont understand can you elaborate. or give some method to check sheet contains formula or not ...

Comment: i need to use which third party tool to use this method or dll ?

Comment: No external tools needed, only standard .NET framework classes.

Comment: always getting error while writing this System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Comment: Why are you writing it? You need to add it to project references in Solution Explorer. You need to check both System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in Add References dialog.

Comment: You need to change the target framework of the current project from .Net 4 to .Net 4.5. Make sure that you did that and re-check your project references. Also see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218602/installed-net-4-5-but-cant-use-zipfile-class-in-visual-c-sharp